# rails 4 recaptcha not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recaptcha

I am trying to use recaptcha in my rails 4 app, but i am missing something as it is not checking it at all.
I am using this gem https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha

Gemfile

```
gem "recaptcha", :require => "recaptcha/rails"
```

.env

```
RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY=6Lf2...
RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY=6Lf2...
```

confir/initializers/recaptcha.rb

```
Recaptcha.configure do |config|
  config.public_key  = ENV["RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY"]
  config.private_key = ENV["RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY"]
  config.proxy = 'http://myproxy.com.au:8080'
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="<%= contact_url %>" id="ajax-contact-form" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="email" id="contact-email" name="email" placeholder="Email..." class="form-control" required>
    <input type="text" id="contact-subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject..." class="form-control" required>
    <textarea id="contact-body" name="body" placeholder="Message..." class="form-control"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Send" class="btn">
    <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>">
    <%= recaptcha_tags %>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

main.coffee

```
$ ->
  sendMessage = () ->
    email = $('#contact-email').val()
    subject = $('#contact-subject').val()
    body = $('#contact-body').val()
    data =
      "email": email
      "subject": subject
      "body": body
      "authenticity_token": $('input[name=authenticity_token]').val()

    $('#ajax-contact-form').hide()
    $('.contact.success-message').html("Thank you, #{email}. We&apos;ll be in touch.")

    posting = $.ajax '/contacts',
      type: 'POST'
      data: JSON.stringify(data)
      dataType: 'json'
      contentType: 'application/json'

    posting.done (data) ->
      console.log "done"

    $('#ajax-contact-form').on 'submit', (e) ->
      e.preventDefault()
      sendMessage()
```

I have nothing in any controllers, I don't know if/where I should have.

Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can check the captcha code by calling `verify_recaptcha` in your controller. The method will return true/false and even set your error message for the captcha (you can customize it with some [options](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha#verify_recaptcha)).